# Using JayData with dynamic init

Tags: javascript, odata, jaydata

i am new with JayData, i have an OData service which i want to consume with JayData
i have this function

```
$data.initService('/odata')
            .then(function (context) {
                // manage your data through context with JSLQ

                context.Store.forEach(function (s) {
                    alert(s.Name);
                    })

            });
```

but the i never get to the foreach
my model is

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

i have changed to use JaySvcUtil - and generated entity model, how ever i got strange request, when it goes to the server i get error 500 cause it use text/plain

```
 var oProviderConfig = {
                name: 'oData',
                oDataServiceHost: 'http://localhost:16894/odata'
            };

            var c = new $data.generatedContexts[0](oProviderConfig);
            c.onReady(function () {
                c._Store.forEach(function (s) {
                    alert(s.Name);
                });
            });
```

GET
500
Internal Server Error
text/plain
datajs-1.1.0.js:2484
Script
358 B
0 B

Comment: raz, Please check the error console of your browser! The following errors can cause the issue:
-missing data.js
-missing jquery
-incorrect order of the included libraries. I datajs must be placed before jaydata, like: jquery, datajs, jaydata
-incorrect service url
-server-side error Let me know if you have a detailed error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var oProviderConfig = {
                name: 'oData',
                oDataServiceHost: 'http://localhost:16894/odata',
                maxDataServiceVersion: '3.0'
            };
```

that fixed it